# Translation Missing Error in Logstash Logs

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I'm trying to feed data in csv files into elastic search using logstash. My logsatsh config file looks like this:

```
input {
    file {
        path => "C:\Users\shreya\Data\RetailData.csv"
        start_position => "beginning" 
        #sincedb_path => "C:\Users\shreya\null"

    }
}
filter {
    csv {
        separator => ","
        id => "Store_ID"
        columns => ["Store","Date","Temperature","Fuel_Price", "MarkDown1", "MarkDown2", "MarkDown3", "MarkDown4", "CPI", "Unemployment", "IsHoliday"]
    }
    mutate {convert => ["Store", "integer"]}
    mutate {convert => ["Date", "date"]}
    mutate {convert => ["Temperature", "float"]}
    mutate {convert => ["Fuel_Price", "float"]}
    mutate {convert => ["CPI", "float"]}
    mutate {convert => ["Unemployment", "float"]}


}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        action => "index"
        hosts => "localhost:9200" 
        index => "store" 
        document_type => "store_retail"     
    }
    stdout {} 
    #stdout {
  #       codec => rubydebug
  #}
}
```

But I'm getting an error and not able to figure out a way to solve that. I'm new to logstash. My error log looks like this:

```
[2017-12-02T15:56:38,150][INFO ][logstash.modules.scaffold] Initializing module {:module_name=>"fb_apache", :directory=>"C:/Users/shreya/logstash-6.0.0/modules/fb_apache/configuration"}
[2017-12-02T15:56:38,165][INFO ][logstash.modules.scaffold] Initializing module {:module_name=>"netflow", :directory=>"C:/Users/shreya/logstash-6.0.0/modules/netflow/configuration"}
[2017-12-02T15:56:38,243][WARN ][logstash.config.source.multilocal] Ignoring the 'pipelines.yml' file because modules or command line options are specified
[2017-12-02T15:56:39,117][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
[2017-12-02T15:56:42,965][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] You are using a deprecated config setting "document_type" set in elasticsearch. Deprecated settings will continue to work, but are scheduled for removal from logstash in the future. Document types are being deprecated in Elasticsearch 6.0, and removed entirely in 7.0. You should avoid this feature If you have any questions about this, please visit the #logstash channel on freenode irc. {:name=>"document_type", :plugin=><LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch action=>"index", hosts=>["localhost:9200"], index=>"store", document_type=>"store_retail", id=>"91a4406a13e9377abb312acf5f6be8e609a685f9c84a5906af957e956119798c">}
[2017-12-02T15:56:43,604][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Elasticsearch pool URLs updated {:changes=>{:removed=>[], :added=>[http://localhost:9200/]}}
[2017-12-02T15:56:43,604][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Running health check to see if an Elasticsearch connection is working {:healthcheck_url=>http://localhost:9200/, :path=>"/"}
[2017-12-02T15:56:43,854][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Restored connection to ES instance {:url=>"http://localhost:9200/"}
[2017-12-02T15:56:43,932][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Using mapping template from {:path=>nil}
[2017-12-02T15:56:43,933][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Attempting to install template {:manage_template=>{"template"=>"logstash-*", "version"=>60001, "settings"=>{"index.refresh_interval"=>"5s"}, "mappings"=>{"_default_"=>{"dynamic_templates"=>[{"message_field"=>{"path_match"=>"message", "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"type"=>"text", "norms"=>false}}}, {"string_fields"=>{"match"=>"*", "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"type"=>"text", "norms"=>false, "fields"=>{"keyword"=>{"type"=>"keyword", "ignore_above"=>256}}}}}], "properties"=>{"@timestamp"=>{"type"=>"date"}, "@version"=>{"type"=>"keyword"}, "geoip"=>{"dynamic"=>true, "properties"=>{"ip"=>{"type"=>"ip"}, "location"=>{"type"=>"geo_point"}, "latitude"=>{"type"=>"half_float"}, "longitude"=>{"type"=>"half_float"}}}}}}}}
[2017-12-02T15:56:43,964][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] New Elasticsearch output {:class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch", :hosts=>["//localhost:9200"]}
[2017-12-02T15:56:44,011][ERROR][logstash.pipeline        ] Error registering plugin {:pipeline_id=>"main", :plugin=>"#<LogStash::FilterDelegator:0x3e4985f1 @metric_events_out=org.jruby.proxy.org.logstash.instrument.metrics.counter.LongCounter$Proxy2 - namespace: [stats, pipelines, main, plugins, filters, e3501f879986420bd95a59d8a1c006d9bc4351a481c96bd5366e7edb54bc6fbb, events] key: out value:0, @metric_events_in=org.jruby.proxy.org.logstash.instrument.metrics.counter.LongCounter$Proxy2 - namespace: [stats, pipelines, main, plugins, filters, e3501f879986420bd95a59d8a1c006d9bc4351a481c96bd5366e7edb54bc6fbb, events] key: in value:0, @logger=#<LogStash::Logging::Logger:0x48eebcf8 @logger=#<Java::OrgApacheLoggingLog4jCore::Logger:0x113b0d16>>, @metric_events_time=org.jruby.proxy.org.logstash.instrument.metrics.counter.LongCounter$Proxy2 - namespace: [stats, pipelines, main, plugins, filters, e3501f879986420bd95a59d8a1c006d9bc4351a481c96bd5366e7edb54bc6fbb, events] key: duration_in_millis value:0, @id=\"e3501f879986420bd95a59d8a1c006d9bc4351a481c96bd5366e7edb54bc6fbb\", @klass=LogStash::Filters::Mutate, @metric_events=#<LogStash::Instrument::NamespacedMetric:0x7c8acc8 @metric=#<LogStash::Instrument::Metric:0x3afcd9b5 @collector=#<LogStash::Instrument::Collector:0x73e63041 @agent=nil, @metric_store=#<LogStash::Instrument::MetricStore:0x60e51f03 @store=#<Concurrent::Map:0x00000000000fb0 entries=3 default_proc=nil>, @structured_lookup_mutex=#<Mutex:0x2209413b>, @fast_lookup=#<Concurrent::Map:0x00000000000fb4 entries=86 default_proc=nil>>>>, @namespace_name=[:stats, :pipelines, :main, :plugins, :filters, :e3501f879986420bd95a59d8a1c006d9bc4351a481c96bd5366e7edb54bc6fbb, :events]>, @filter=<LogStash::Filters::Mutate convert=>{\"Date\"=>\"date\"}, id=>\"e3501f879986420bd95a59d8a1c006d9bc4351a481c96bd5366e7edb54bc6fbb\", enable_metric=>true, periodic_flush=>false>>", :error=>"translation missing: en.logstash.agent.configuration.invalid_plugin_register", :thread=>"#<Thread:0x3cc2461b@C:/Users/shreya/logstash-6.0.0/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:290 run>"}
[2017-12-02T15:56:44,042][ERROR][logstash.pipeline        ] Pipeline aborted due to error {:pipeline_id=>"main", :exception=>#<LogStash::ConfigurationError: translation missing: en.logstash.agent.configuration.invalid_plugin_register>, :backtrace=>["C:/Users/shreya/logstash-6.0.0/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/logstash-filter-mutate-3.1.6/lib/logstash/filters/mutate.rb:186:in `block in register'", "org/jruby/RubyHash.java:1343:in `each'", "C:/Users/shreya/logstash-6.0.0/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/logstash-filter-mutate-3.1.6/lib/logstash/filters/mutate.rb:184:in `register'", "C:/Users/shreya/logstash-6.0.0/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:388:in `register_plugin'", "C:/Users/shreya/logstash-6.0.0/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:399:in `block in register_plugins'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1734:in `each'", "C:/Users/shreya/logstash-6.0.0/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:399:in `register_plugins'", "C:/Users/shreya/logstash-6.0.0/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:801:in `maybe_setup_out_plugins'", "C:/Users/shreya/logstash-6.0.0/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:409:in `start_workers'", "C:/Users/shreya/logstash-6.0.0/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:333:in `run'", "C:/Users/shreya/logstash-6.0.0/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:293:in `block in start'"], :thread=>"#<Thread:0x3cc2461b@C:/Users/shreya/logstash-6.0.0/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:290 run>"}
[2017-12-02T15:56:44,058][ERROR][logstash.agent           ] Failed to execute action {:id=>:main, :action_type=>LogStash::ConvergeResult::FailedAction, :message=>"Could not execute action: LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main, action_result: false", :backtrace=>nil}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from the convert target in one of the mutate filters. From the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-convert):

> Valid conversion targets are: integer, float, string, and boolean.

So this part is causing the crash:

```
mutate {convert => ["Date", "date"]}
```

If you want a to convert a String to a date, you'll have to use the date filter.

Answer (score 1):

Validate your config file using below command, that shows the error details.

```
./logstash -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/your_config_file.conf --config.test_and_exit
```